# Attempting to present modal results in exception: _descendantWillPresentViewController

Tags: ios, ios9

I'm getting a very strange issue. This code worked fine in iOS 8, but is now resulting in a crash in **iOS 9**.

All I'm doing is presenting a view controller modally:

`[self presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:YES completion:nil];`

However this results in an exception:

> -[TTSplitViewController _descendantWillPresentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animated:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8898c716a0

It's worth noting too that `TTSplitViewController` is not what `viewControllerToPresent` is. `viewControllerToPresent` is just a regular UIViewController. Not sure why my custom `TTSplitViewController` is getting involved here.

The `TTSplitViewController` instance is however a child view controller of `self` in this case (self being the one presenting the modal).

Any ideas what this could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out the issue. My `TTSplitViewController` property was called `splitViewController`, which conflicted with UIKit's own `splitViewController` property. Renaming this to something else did the trick.

Comment: I've actually filed a radar to apple about this for not throwing a compiler warning that there are conflicting variables. Thanks for finding this, it would have taken me forever